# SFTP Connecton error

Tags: android

I want to build an Android app that uses sftp protocol, but I'm getting an authentication fail error by using password field :

```
try {
    JSch ssh = new JSch();

    Session session = ssh.getSession("xxxx", "xxxxxxxx.com", 22);

    java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();

    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setConfig(config);
    session.setPassword("xxxxxxx");

    session.connect();
    Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
    channel.connect();

    ChannelSftp sftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;

    sftp.get("/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/test/Test.txt", "/sdcard/text.txt");

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DOWNLOAD SUCCESSFULL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    channel.disconnect();
    session.disconnect();
} catch (JSchException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage().toString());
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"JSCh ERROR",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SftpException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage().toString());
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SFTP ERROR",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are still facing the issue then,
-Check from server side if u have the access, try to connect using the provided username and password in browser.If that works check server side what are the authentication types provided.Sometime it is key only and if that is the case ask to change in server settings to give authentication as password also.